# От какого слова образовано "нужно"?

Tags: словообразование

"Нужно" - категория состояния.
Способ словообразования - морфолого-синтаксический.
Из какой части речи произошёл переход?

Comment: От какого слова образован "нужник"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Слово категории состояния "нужно" образовано от краткого прилагательного  среднего рода "нУжно".

Полная форма прилагательного - нужный, краткие формы: нужен, нужна, нУжно, нужны.

Comment: То есть это переход одной части речи в другую?

Comment: Да, это переход. Слово категории состояния "нужно" по форме совпадает с кратким прилагательным "нужно", но перед нами уже другая часть речи: неизменяемая, совмещающая в себе свойства глагола и наречия и выполняющая функцию главного члена безличного предложения.

Answer (score 2):

Вероятно от старого "нужа" (= нужда, подобная пара "хОженье - хождение"

От него же в наследство остался и НУЖНИК, так можно полагать....